# SwiftUI TextField not getting updated variable

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, textfield

I have a TextField that is bound to a `@Published` variable `text`.
I have a `isDisabled` var that checks `text` to see if it is empty that impacts other things in the view. (let's say it changes the color of a button in the view)

I want to call a function when editing of the `TextField` is done but I want to make sure `isDisabled != true` before it executes without needing to repeat the same rules inside the `TextField` closure.

I would like to understand why `isDisabled` is not getting an updated value inside the closure when it does outside (the color of the button is performing as expected), and what solve might I employ to not have to repeat the `isDisabled` logic inside the `TextField` closure

Here is some simple code demonstrating:
The first Text view is getting the updated values of isDisabled, however the TextField is not and thus fails the check

```
struct SwiftUIViewOne: View {
    
    @State var text:String = ""
    
    var body: some View {
        
        SwiftUIViewTwo(
            text: $text
            , isDisabled: text.isEmpty
        )
        
    }

}

struct SwiftUIViewTwo: View {
    
    @Binding var text:String
    
    @State var textFieldsOpinion:Bool = true
    
    var isDisabled:Bool = false
    
    var body: some View {
        
        VStack {
            
            Spacer()
            
            TextField("message", text: $text, onEditingChanged: { edit in

                textFieldsOpinion = isDisabled
                
                /// This does not work
                if !edit && !isDisabled {
                    
                    text = "Edit Complete; checked isDisabled"
                    // In reality we want to call function when Edit is Complete
                   
                /// This works, however I have to re-write the isDisabled Logic from SwiftUiViewOne
                } else if !edit && !text.isEmpty {
                    
                    text = "Edit Complete; checked !text.isEmpty"
                    // In reality we want to call function when Edit is Complete
                }
                
            })
            
            Spacer()
            
            Text(text)
            
            Text("isDisabled = \(isDisabled ? "True" : "False")")
            Text("TextField thinks it is = \(textFieldsOpinion ? "True" : "False")")
            
            Spacer()
            
            
        }
        
    }

}
```

Comment: Unless you declare it `@State`, `@StateObject`, `@ObservedObject` or `@Binding`, it can't update. Remember, you are dealing with a struct and they are immutable. However, since `Binding var text:String` is the same as in the parent view, you can simply key off of that with a computed variable.

Comment: Was walking down that road... however, as in the example, some parts of the view ARE getting the updated value.  I guess I am not understanding why they are, but the TextField is not.  Oh, and I tried the @State route with the same results

Comment: Without the MRE, we can't see what you are seeing so pretty tough to debug.